# Change color to a JPanel and return to original

Tags: java, swing, colors, jpanel

I need to change the color to my jPanel, that's easy, but then you can return to the original color.
The application can change color at any time, so can not be a static color, must vary according to the background color of the application.

Im trying this:

```
Color defaultColor;  
defaultColor = m_jButtons.getBackground();  
m_jButtons.setBackground(Color.red);  
//And then  
m_jButtons.setBackground(Color.defaultColor);
```

`m_jButtons.setBackground(Color.defaultColor);` this wont work (logically).
Anyone knows any method to do that?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  BTW - it seems that whatever is changing the BG color of the 'default color' should also change the color in the panel.  So I don't really understand what the problem is.

Comment: @AndrewThompson What do you think I can edit to improve that question? I'm not good at english and I'm trying to do my best
EDIT: There's no method like setBackground(Color.java.awt.Color)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because the color you definded is not part of the java.awt.Color class

You should do

```
m_jButtons.setBackground(defaultColor);
```

assuming the variable is accessible from where you want to set it.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know it could be so easy!